# undefined variable in construct function

Tags: php, scope, visibility

I think this might be a simple issue of variable scope, but I'm stumped as to where the issue lies.  Given the following lines of code

```
class mysqlaccess {

private $creds;
private $error;
protected $con;
public $dir;

public function __construct () {
        $this->$dir = "../../../../../private/mysqlinfo.ini";
    }

}
```

when I try to reference this public variable from another file like so

```
include_once ('mysqlaccess.php');

$s = new mysqlaccess();

echo $s->dir;
```

I get the following errors

undefined variable dir

and 
cannot access empty property

my understanding was that this was how the construct function was supposed to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You assign `$this->$dir` and then attempt to access it with `$s->dir`...

Comment: why $dir in the first one and just dir in the 2nd?
Also, I'm not sure you should get to ini files like that.

Comment: Typo: `$this->$dir = ` instead of `$this->dir`. The error message even mentions the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo here -

```
$this->$dir = "..
       ^
```

should be

```
$this->dir = "..
```

Answer (score 2):

You need: `$this->dir` instead of `$this->$dir`.

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) as example.

You have to use this(without $):

```
 $this->dir
```